# How do I read comments from XML file using XDocument.Load() in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a XML in the following format:

```
<break name="Chapter01">
<!--Chapter 1-->
<p class="para">Some value</p>
</break>
<break name="Chapter02">
<!--Chapter 2-->
<p class="para">Some value</p>
</break>
<break name="Chapter03">
<p class="para">Some value</p>
</break>
```

When I am loading the file using `XDocument.Load(fileName)`, all the comments are gone.

It is becoming:

```
<break name="Chapter01">
<p class="para">Some value</p>
</break>
<break name="Chapter02">
<p class="para">Some value</p>
</break>
<break name="Chapter03">
<p class="para">Some value</p>
</break>
```

How do I preserve the comments when reading the file using `XDocument.Load()`?

Comment: *"It is becoming"* - what becoming? How do you produce second output exactly?

Comment: As soon as `XDocument.Load(fileName)` is executed, the comments are gone in the `XDocument` variable. Also, the possible duplicate question is not really what I need. I have done all the things needed to be done and now it is a new feature request that I read from comments as well.

Comment: I tested your text with `XDocument.Parse` - and everything is fine. Perhaps, there's something is going on we don't see.

Answer (score -3):

You could try loading the file without XDocument and load it normally and then make a REGEX expression.

Comment: `XDocument` can read comments, see [XComment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcomment?view=netframework-4.8).